# Angular - replacing filters with ng-show in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been running into some performance issues with my Angular Material app on IE11 and have been investigating mutliple issues.  I've taken some steps to rectify based on the official suggestions, but I noticed something I think is causing a lot of the issue.

We have a product page with a set of tabs that displays/hides products based on the currently selected category.  The largest amount of delay happens when clicking between tabs.  I *think* this is because the filters we apply destroy/recreate the DOM each time the tab is clicked off of.  I'd like to use `ng-show` because that seems to rectify the issue, but we are using nested `ng-repeat` directives so I'm not sure if that will work.  Here is the general idea of what is going on:

```
<div ng-repeat="InventoryItemSubCategory in vmProduct.products | filter: ($scope.selectedGroup !== 'All' || '') && $scope.selectedGroup | filter:$scope.query | groupBy:'InventoryItemSubCategory':'productsByCategory' track by $index">
<h2>{{InventoryItemSubCategory.InventoryItemSubCategory}}</h2>

<md-card class="product-card" ng-repeat="product in InventoryItemSubCategory.items track by $index" md-theme="default" md-theme-watch>
  <md-card-content>
    <div class="media">
    ...
```

The idea is that each tab (group) has multiple subgroups which each have multiple items.  The problem is, if I try to use an `ng-show` on the top level `ng-repeat`, it does not filter the array like the filter does so the inner `ng-repeat` elements do not display correctly.

So my question is, is that indeed the issue I'm running into?  And if so, is there a clean way to use `ng-show` but also filter a parent array so it can be appropriately used by a child `ng-repeat`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: update your post with the relevant json data along with **Filter** code.

Comment: The JSON is quite extensive (it comes from a SharePoint list) but it is trimmed down before it gets to this point.  As far as the filter code, it is all there, right?  There are no methods behind the scenes that do any filtering besides what you see here.  `selectedGroup` is the chosen DOM tab and `query` corresponds to a search box we have at the top of the page.

Comment: then do update the code with your filter code. Which can help what is that your are passing in and returning back

Comment: I think the question is more general than a specific filter, I really am just looking for whether or not you can do this with *any* filter.  By this I mean narrow down an array but use something like `ng-show` or `ng-hide` instead of a filter proper due to the overhead of how it performs DOM manipulation rather than using styles to show/hide elements.